# Расшифровка строки зашифрованной методом вертикальной перестановки

Tags: шифрование

Есть очень старый шифр методом вертикальной перестановки("столбцовый метод"), но у меня возникла проблема в расшифровке сообщения. Может кто-то подсказать, как расшифровать эти сообщения(каким методом обратно выставить столбцы)? Не знаю как узнать реальную длину столбца. В литературе рассказывают только метод шифрования, а если и расшифровки, то только для полностью заполненной таблицы, в случае текста из примера он выдаст неверный ответ. Пример:

```
C R Y P T O
1 4 6 3 5 2
H E L L O W
O R L D     //Шифр HOWLDEROLL
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ключ здесь `1 4 6 3 5 2`, его длина 6, так что мы знаем, что шифровка длиной 10 включает в себя четыре столбца длиной 2 и 2 неполных столбца длиной 1. Кроме того, ключ неявно содержит таблицу перестановки (как индекс)

```
 ключ K     1 4 6 3 5 2
 длина L    2 2 2 2 1 1   
 индекс I   1 2 3 4 5 6   

 1:HO 2:W 3:LD 4:ER 5:O 6:LL
```

Так что для k-й части входной строки находим в ключе элемент k, его индекс i, длина части L[i], и записываем в i-й столбец выходной таблицы L[i] символов.

Comment: Спасибо большое, вы очень помогли